# Button disable function after clicking on it

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have   save  button  in around  150 pages. when ever the user  clicks on save  button  i should  disable  the  button after the click. so that user  does not keep  clicking on save button  again.

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // right now once the  user  clicks the save button
       Button1.Enabled = "false"

    }
```

right now i am  doing like  this. is there any better  solution  u can  provide me  to improve   codeing here would be great.

thank you

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your current solution?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best option to accomplish this is using javascript. If you are using jQuery (which I can even start to recommend enough) then you can put the javascript in your masterpage. You just need to find a way to create a selector for your save buttons. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.saveButton').bind("click", function(e) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
            return true; //causes the client side script to run.
        });
    });
```

In this example, I assumed that all the save buttons would have the css class ".saveButton", but you can find your own way to select the button.

Cheers!

Comment: @Gus: if you post code like your jQuery snippet, make sure to highlight the lines and then click on the "code" button (010 101) on the editor toolbar or press Ctrl-K on your keyboard to neatly format it as code. Then and only then will it be syntax highlighted and all.

Comment: hi  Gus,
thanks for the  replay if i use the  above  code  in master page.
intally  during   the click  of the  button  it should  get  ex
try
{  public  void  save function()
{
// here   all  save  button  should be  disabled

}

catch(exception e)
{
throw  e;
}
finally
{
//here  my  save  button   should  be  Enabled
// finally  my save button  should  get  enable here
}
}

Answer (score 2):

You can also try disabling it via Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript to alter the link once it's clicked to prevent future click handling, before allowing the page to proceed with the postback.  A naive attempt would be,

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="button" OnClientClick="this.href='#'">
    Click - doesn't quite work
</asp>
```

This successfully prevents successive clicks from triggering the postback, but it also prevents the first click from triggering the postback. A little more logic is required to make this work correctly. In the codebehind, I grab the actual postback JavaScript snippet and work it into some logic.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.OnClientClick = string.Format(
        "if(this.getAttribute('disabled')) return false; {0}; this.setAttribute('disabled','disabled'); return false;",
        Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(button1, null));
}
```

In the HTML template:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="button" >
    Click - does not allow multiple postbacks
</asp>
```

You can spruce this up with some CSS, and at that point I would advise including jQuery, so your code is more concise (due to its command chaining).

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is use some JavaScript and disable it when its clicked on the client side.

That click event fires on a postback.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way of attaching javascript to disable the button after user click would be this (in page onLoad event):

```
myButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave, null) + ";");
```

But if button is repeated on many pages, you can maybe create nested master page and put save button there, or inherit you page from class that implements this disable functionality. Also, you can "scan" for control you want to disable after click!